# my computer refuses to boot after a sleep

Tags: windows-7

I have a PC with windows 7 and 8 dual booted..7  was set to sleep automatically  .yesterday I switched off the ups directly when it was on sleep 
Now it refuses to boot.windows bootloader  doesn't  shows up ,after Bois it goes for a restart ,and keep doing that ,like forever 
I have  boot able  USBs of mint 16 and backtrack 5. Now can I get those  windows back or I need to reinstall  windows ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why,
But by just booting from bootable windows USB fixed my PC.
**PS :** I didn't repaired or formatted my device just a simple boot(from external windows bootable drive)  fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Advanced Boot Options](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/advanced-startup-options-including-safe-mode) (F8 key immediately after POST) and run [Startup Repair](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/startup-repair-faq).  If you're unable to get to Advanced Boot Options, use your Windows installation disc to run Startup Repair.